# click event occurs with onload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and am trying to code a click event handler for an html button element with id="display". When I use a window.onload function and add my .onclick event it runs when the window loads and doesn't wait for the click event. I have tried .addEventListener('click', dispResults) method and although the dispResults function doesn't run onload, it doesn't run with the click event either. Please help...

```
var names = ["Ben", "Joel", "Judy", "Anne"];
var scores = [88, 98, 77, 88];

var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var dispResults = function () {
    var avg;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        total = total + scores[i];
    }
    avg = total/scores.length;
    $("results").value = avg.toFixed(0);
}

window.onload = function () {
    $("display").onclick = dispResults();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Short answer: remove the `()` from `= displayResults()`, because that is what calls the function. It is possible the problem you mention with `.addEventListener('click', dispResults)` is *not* a duplicate, because that should work given you put `dispResults` without the `()`, but you don't actually show that in context - if you want help with that please [edit] your question to cover that specifically and we could reopen it.

Comment: P.S. Why the jQuery flag? It is confusing when you have defined your own `$()` function as a shortcut to `getElementById()`, and don't use any jQuery in your code.

Comment: I added the jquery flag as the class I am taking is javascript and jquery. I don't really understand yet where the line is between the two. It works great without the parentheses as you point out. What are the parentheses really doing when left in place?

Comment: Did you read the answers at the linked duplicate? The parentheses call the function. If you say `$("display").onclick = dispResults()` that immediately calls the `dispResults` function and then assigns its return value (which is `undefined`) to the onclick. If you say `$("display").onclick = dispResults` then that assigns a reference to the function to the onlcick.

Comment: Regarding JavaScript versus jQuery: JavaScript is a language. jQuery is not a language, it is "just" some JavaScript code that somebody else wrote to create a collection of useful functions so that you don't have to bother writing them yourself. That is, jQuery is a library of useful JavaScript functions, most of which are for manipulating HTML elements.